# How can I replace the term "Week" in highcharts Gantt Chart Timeline?

Tags: highcharts, gantt-chart

Highcharts language options unfortunately do not provide a parameter for the term "week", therefore in the timeline header of the gantt chart the term "Week" could not be translated (into german "Woche" or "KW" in my case)

The API docs for the several options of Highcharts.setOptions({
      lang: {...} do not provide a translation for "week". I have tried "week" and "weeks" to see if these params exist without being documented but that wont work either.

So it seemst that is is not possible to change the term "Week" with the language options? Is there another possibility? Or will this option be added in future releases?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the term "Week" in `dateTimeLabelFormats`:

```
xAxis: [{
    ...
}, {
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        week: 'Woche %W'
    }
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vw7hjg64/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/gantt/xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats.week

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `dateTimeLabelFormats.xAxis.list` as a list of options since both the short format (W1) or long format (Week 1) maybe used depending on the zoom level.

You also have to defined it twice (for the 2 rows of the headers) by settings `xAxis` as an array where the first element is the configuration for the bottom row and the second for the top row:

```
this.gantt = HighchartsGantt.ganttChart('gantt', {
    // ...

    xAxis: [{
       // ...
       dateTimeLabelFormats: {
         week: {
           list: [ 'Semaine %W', 'S%W' ]
         } as Highcharts.AxisDateTimeLabelFormatsOptionsObject
       }
    }, {
       dateTimeLabelFormats: {
         week: {
           list: [ 'Semaine %W', 'S%W' ]
         } as Highcharts.AxisDateTimeLabelFormatsOptionsObject
       }
    }]

    // ...
});
```

And if you use typescript you'll have to cast the `week` property to `Highcharts.AxisDateTimeLabelFormatsOptionsObject` (I didn't find any proper typings for these specific Gantt options).

References :
https://api.highcharts.com/gantt/xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats
https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=43936#p155436